# Can't run the .java file

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I might have a problem. I have homework, and I can't run the file, whenever I open the file that I downloaded it looks like this:

[image]

I just can't figure it out, why it doesn't look like any normal class. Plus just for testing I wrote later the main method to try something simple, it won't even show me the option to run the file. Please any help would be really appreciated.

(Just to be clear I am not asking help on the homework, just on the file, that I downloaded, I can't even program in the way it is right now)

Comment: cant see the image on the link

Comment: try to run the .class file instead

Comment: I don't have a .class file, all we got was the .java files, and some others to test @Stultuske .

Comment: And sorry about that, here I will upload another link (I don't know if I can post pictures here?) http://prntscr.com/73zhtd @SaurabhJhunjhunwala

Comment: So, you have a class, you don't compile it, and try to run it? I recommend you to first learn the basics. uninstall every IDE you have installed, and start of with any text editor you have and the command prompt.
Trust me: skipping the first ten chapters of your textbook because they're boring does not make you learn Java faster.

Comment: I have a .java file not a .class file, and I didn't skip the first 10 chapters, this is the algorithms class, it is not the programming one. And I know how to do the main method, as I said I can write OTHER classes, but whenever I open this file via IntelliJ it doesn't show up like the other used to. Even when I write the main method (which I know that is essential to run the class) it is not going to change anything http://prntscr.com/73zlqr

Comment: Forget about using text editors and command line and read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30168344/cant-run-the-java-file/30168933#30168933 and the help pages from JetBrains...

Answer (score 1):

The file shown Tree.java doesn't have a main method, if you want to run this file in the Editor, add the main method.
Eg:

```
public class Tree
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
         System.out.println("Calling main");
    }
}
```

Refer to **[this link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/?hc_location=ufi)** for more details.

Comment: I know that, I wrote it that in the screenshot it doesn't but adding it is not going to change anything, it still looks the same: http://prntscr.com/73zlqr

Answer (score 0):

Two problems, the file is not on the classpath/Source Root (read this https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/content-root.html)  and it does not have a main method.

Try to create and run a new java project from the `Java Hello World` template or https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/creating-and-running-your-first-java-application.html

You could then copy your files into that, so that you have a following directory structure: `YourProject/src/asd1/ss15/...`

Answer (score 0):

In the side panel, go to your project files, right click the directory in which your .java files are, and

"Mark directory as" >> Source code.

And now you will be able to use these files as normal class files.

Answer (score -5):

I just saw your code and looks like you are far away from what you need.

Let me give you some tips:

- Try use a good IDE like eclipse
- Study about how to create and use a main method
- Study how to set in eclipse to use the main method when you run your project
- Study how to export your project a runnable jar if you are thinking in a desktop app
- Check if JAVA is installed in you machine

If my question is helpful give a up vote.

Cheers !!

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think that IDE is the problem, because I also tried it on NetBeans. Java is INStALLED on my omputer, I have programmed before, and I still can when I make new classes, it's just that with this particular file I am having difficulties. And also can I ask why are people down voting my question? What did I do/say wrong :( ?

Comment: Did you read the part of my comment about main class ? public static void main(String[] args) is your friend ! About the down vote, I hate when people use down vote and do not add a single comment explaining why. I just gave you a up vote for you !

Comment: Yes thanks buddy :) Ofc that I know about the main method, but it doesn't change anything http://prntscr.com/73zlqr sadly...

Comment: I have no idea, I tried upvoting your, but I can't do that since I have a below 15 reputation since I am new here...

Comment: Check in your IDE for run/debug settings and check launch configuration if it is set to run your main class that has a main function

Comment: I gave you a downvote because it is as far away from the question as OP is from the solution. Also it contains really bad suggestion: ```Try use a good IDE like eclipse```

Comment: Meo, BetimNeutron seems to be happy with the question, if you read the comments he is also trying to give me a up vote. You are wrong ! Also if you think you could answer better than me, do it !

Comment: @Igor This is down-voted because it does not give an answer, only suggestions. With that you don't ask for up-votes.